# Simulation of a rocket with no fins

Tags: launch, rockets

I setup a simple rocket in openrocket with a body to fit the engine and a nose cone.  I did not add fins.  This puts the center of pressure up in the nose cone way ahead of the center of gravity.  What I am trying to do is setup a situation where you would use gimbaling to stabilize the rocket but in an environment where it may not be necessary so I turned off wind for the simulation.  The rocket still goes unstable and I'm curious why.  It seems to remain unstable until I make fins large enough to move the center of pressure behind the center of gravity.

It appears I can remove air pressure in which case the simulation does work, so I'm guessing there is some non-uniformity somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

If the center of pressure is ahead of the center of gravity, even the slightest difference will cause a divergence -- even a rounding difference or numerical representation in your simulation code.  It is your second simulation that "works" that is really not working.  You have what is known as an unstable equilibrium.

[image]

Comment: Good point about the numerical representation and rounding errors.